# List View with images and text

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

I'm trying to do a List that shows an image and a simple text describing the image.
In my search on internet I found many ways to do this. Some people using ArrayAdapter, others using SimpleCursorAdapter. One thing I notice, many people are creating classes inheriting from ListActivity and in the `setListAdapter` method they are inserting other classes derived from Array or SimpleCursor adapter.
First question: is this the best way to do this?

I created a LinearLayout with a ListView inside. And to insert rows, another layout was created with an `ImageView` and a `TextView`.
Second question: is this correct?

I'm confusing about creation of this type of component. Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, although you will need to use a `CursorAdapter` instead of a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, since the point of a `SimpleCursorAdapter` is to populate a row with only a `TextView` in it.

You will have a `getView` method on your `CursorAdapter` that expands your row layout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) { // we don't have a recycled view
        convertView = LayoutInflator.from(getContext()).inflate(
          R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    // setup our row
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    text.setText( ... );
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    image.setImageBitmap( ... );
    return convertView;
}
```

When you're setting the text and image of your views, you can use adapter methods like `getItem` to access the underlying data you need.